# Dropdown menu dinâmico html

Tags: jquery, html, dropdown

Olá,

Tenho essa página em html e gostaria de saber como posso fazer para que ao alterar o item escolhido no menu dropdown, os campos do html se alterem.

```
<fieldset id="fsItem">
                <legend>Item &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                    <button id="bAnt"><</button>
                    <input type="text" class="input" id="idItem" value="0" disabled>
                    <button  id="bNex">></button>
                    <button  id="bAdd">+</button>
                    <button  id="bRem">&ndash;</button>
                </legend>
                <label>Item</label>
                    <select>
                        <option value="person">Person</option>
                        <option value="vehicle">Vehicle</option>
                        <option value="animal">Animal</option>
                    </select>
                <p><label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="input" id="nameItem" value="" disabled>
                <p><label>Age</label>
                <input type="text" class="input" id="ageItem" value="" disabled>
                <label id="lbAs">Associate</label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="input" id="chkAs" value=""></p>
                <p><label>Details</label>
                <textarea class="input" id="detailsItem" rows=5 disabled></textarea></p>
```

A página default seria "Person". Ao selecionar "Vehicle", por exemplo, os campos "Name" e "Age" seriam substituídos por "Type" e "Color". O "Associate" sumiria.

Desde já obrigado,

Comment: Fica difícil dar uma resposta boa porque to no APP do celular e o texto seria grande! Mas vou dar só uma ideia. Pensa como se seus "option" fosse um link ancora. Que ao selecionar você iria disparar uma função! No caso você pode disparar uma função que vai ler o atributo value. Com esse atributo você vai gerar uma nova função e vai aplicar seu resultado ao label referente  ao option selecionado!

Comment: obrigado pela idéia!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('select').change(function() { 
    $('.item').hide();
    $('.item-' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

```css
.item-vehicle,
.item-animal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Item</label>
<select>
  <option value="person">Person</option>
  <option value="vehicle">Vehicle</option>
  <option value="animal">Animal</option>
</select>

<!-- Agrupamento dos campos Person -->
<div class="item item-person">
  <p>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text">
  </p>

  <p>
    <label>Age</label>
    <input type="text">
  </p>

  <p>
    <label>Associate</label>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </p>
</div>

<!-- Agrupamento dos campos Vehicle -->
<div class="item item-vehicle">
  <p>
    <label>Type</label>
    <input type="text">
  </p>

  <p>
    <label>Color</label>
    <input type="text">
  </p>
</div>

<!-- Agrupamento dos campos Animal -->
<div class="item item-animal">
  formulário...
</div>

<!-- Campos comuns entre os três -->
<p>
  <label>Details</label>
  <textarea class="input"></textarea>
</p>
```

Olhe se o exemplo atende.
Primeiro agrupei os campos para cada tipo do dropdown. Repare que eles possuem uma classe que é item-[valor do dropdown selecionado].

Assim que ocorrer qualquer modificação no campo dropdown é escondido todos os agrupamentos com a classe item. Obtenho o valor selecionado e monto um novo seletor. Assim se selecionar a opção vehicle é exibido a div com a classe item-vehicle.

Comment: Fiquei com dúvida no código  .item-vehicle,
.item-animal {
  display: none;
}. A resposta está muito bem explicada! Obrigado!